# When connecting two Android phones via a cable, how can I choose which phone is charging which phone?

Tags: charging, android-12, google-pixel-6

When connecting two Android phones via a cable, how can I choose which phone is charging which phone? E.g. when I connected a Samsung Galaxy S9 (Android 10) with a Google Pixel 6 (Android 12) via a male-to-male USB-C cable, the Google Pixel 6 got charged.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Under USB preferences, whichever device has *Charge connected device* as *enabled* is charging the other device.

Snapshot from Pixel 4a (Android 12) connected to and charging One Plus 7 (Android 10)

[image]

And the reverse (One Plus charging Pixel)

[image]

If you want to switch charging when connected, toggle the switch on any device and the selection on the other device gets reversed.

**Edit:** To address the comments, charging **cannot** be switched off on both devices. I couldn't find any documentation around this.

Comment: Looks like this feature was [added since Android 9 Pie](https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/03/08/android-p-feature-spotlight-usb-menu-gets-revamped-lets-transfer-files-charge-connected-device-simultaneously/).

Comment: *If you want to switch charging when connected, toggle the switch on any device and the selection on the other device gets reversed* seems less than ideal - what if you want no charging to take place at all?

Comment: @ChrisH: Then presumably you'd set it to "off" on both phones, instead of "on" on one or the other.

Comment: @PeterCordes that's what I'd hope to happen, but "toggling one reverses the other" means that when you turn one off the other turns on

Comment: Regarding charging not being able to be switched off completely on both, I bet this has something to do with USB certification. There are all kinds of seemingly odd edge cases involved there, and it would not surprise me if one o them is ‘no data transfer without power transfer’.